# Full example application using Prism 4

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am looking for a Prism 4 sample application in order to learn it and got things faster. I have been looking on the web, but there are few such things available and most of them are not suitalbe for me.

I have checked some of the applications available on the net, and please DO NOT POST LINKS to some of the following:

Karl Shifflet on MVVP and it's media box or something http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/in-the-box-ndash-mvvm-training/

Home page of Patterns and Practices Prism http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/

I have checked the above links and I have found lots of information, some useful, some not. I am looking for a working application using Prism 4, with good WPF UI and if possible, available usage of some database product, MS SQL or other. I need only base things, two-three windows and navigation between them, some checking logic and that's it, i don't need big or commercial sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samples included with PRISM cover all you need. Also, PRISM is about UI composition, data access is out of scope.

I'm working on such a project and book on PRISM from patterns and practices team was very helpful